# The shortcut to access the Menubar via the Keyboard does not work in Excel or PowerPoint for macOS

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, menu-bar

I have mapped the `Move Focus to the menu bar` to <kbd>CMD</kbd> - <kbd>'</kbd>.  This works for example, on Chrome.  It also happens to work in Word: you can see the Apple icon is activated, so then I can use mnemonics (first letter) of the menu items to get to the submenu e.g. <kbd>V</kbd> for `View`:

[image]

It does not however work for Excel or PowerPoint. I even tried the default <kbd>Ctl</kbd> - <kbd>F2</kbd> as well as <kbd>CMD</kbd> - <kbd>F2</kbd>): nothing works to get to the menu.

I am a keyboardist and slowed down [and annoyed] quite a bit by needing to jump to the mouse for everything.  Is there a workaround/fix?

Comment: Does Cmd/Shift/forward slash [/] work to get to the Help menu? What versions macOS & Office?

Comment: @Tetsujin  Yes those work. I found out the key combo is already mapped to something else in those programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that both `Excel` and `PowerPoint` have already mapped the <kbd>CMD'</kbd> to something else.  I changed the mapping to `Shift-CMD-SPACE` and that works.